# How I would to select all employees who don't participate in this training? (using select from two tables)

Tags: php, mysql

How I would to select all employees who don't participate in this training? (using select from two tables)

I have two tables. Name of first table is 'employee', name of second table is 'employee_to_training'.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employee_to_training` (
`id_emp_training` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_employee` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_training` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=20 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employee` (
`employeeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
  `MiddleName` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
  `Sex` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET cp1251 NOT NULL,
  `birthday` date NOT NULL,
  `image_location` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `date_on_work` date NOT NULL,
  `pos` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `rating` int(250) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=273 ;
```

Also I have third table that named is 'training'.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `training` (
`id_training` int(100) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `current_count` int(250) NOT NULL,
  `max_count` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `date_to_start` date NOT NULL,
  `date_to_finish` date NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `status_training` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `degree` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `add_to_score` int(250) NOT NULL,
  `time_training` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;
```

**My code:**

```
<div class="bs-callout bs-callout-danger">
        <h4>List of employees who still don't take part in this training</h4>
        <table class="table table-striped table-responsive ">
          <thead>
            <tr><th>Last Name, First Name, MiddleName</th>
            <th>Position</th>
          </tr></thead>
          <tbody>


<?php $emp_query=mysql_query("select * from employee, employee_to_training where (employee_to_training.id_training<>'$get_id')");

                        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($emp_query)){ $id=$row['employeeID']; ?>

            <tr>

              <td><a href="" class=""><?php echo $row['LastName'] . ' ' . $row['FirstName'] . ' ' . $row['MiddleName']; ?></a></td>
              <td><?php echo $row['pos']; ?></td>
            </tr>
<?php } ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
```

The variable $get_id means id of training.
Help me to draw up the correct query.

Comment: Please rephrase your question it's unclear. Also some table formatting would be nice to visualize the content of database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, this should work:

```
$emp_query = mysql_query(
"SELECT e.* 
FROM employee e 
LEFT JOIN employee_to_training et ON (et. e.employeeID AND et.id_training ='{$get_id}') 
WHERE et.id_emp_training IS NULL");
```

Comment: while($row=mysql_fetch_array($emp_query)){ $id=$row['employeeID'];?>

Comment: I add this string to your code and I receive following error: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: A long, long time ago, it was decided that PHP's mysql API was no longer fit for purpose. As a result, new APIs were provided.

Comment: add this to display if there's an error
    if($emp_query === FALSE) { 
        die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling } before the while($row=mysql_fetch_array($emp_query)){ $id=$row['employeeID'];?>